# Android Studio - get keystore file .jks

Tags: android, android-keystore

Recently I have formatted my mac and made a clean installation of Android Studio. I have update one of my app and its ready to be uploaded in the google play store. The Android studio projects was copied in my hard drive However, I have a big problem I cannot find my `keystore.jks` in order to sign the release. I have all the passwords written down `Key store password` and `key password` but I don't have the file.

Is there a way to get the `.jks` file from the project folder I have copied in my hard drive, or another way to generate the keystore file if I know the passwords?

Comment: the process of generating keystore file isn't working? You can again regenerate the keystore file

Comment: How can I regenerate it? I only know the passwords. I have tried with Android studio when I build for release to create a new file using the passwords but it's not accept it on google play